# Compilation error executing basic if else statements

Tags: java

I had a similar code to this using numbers, and it worked perfectly. This however keeps underlining the word else and I don't know why. I am just playing around with java trying to understand a few principles.

I want to program to reply one of two statements depending on input. Also, where it says  `if (input1 == "Hello");`, I wanted to put  `if (input1 == "Hello" || "hello");` to accept lowercase too, but that showed errors too.

Just to be clear, if i remove the else clause, my program runs and both statements are printed!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    System.out.println("Hello there!");
    Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    String input1 = Scan.nextLine();
    Scan.close();

    if (input1 == "Hello");
        {
            System.out.println("How are you?");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("How rude, you didn't even say Hello!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this as an *exact* duplicate.  The duplicate question could be updated to include an answer in regards to comparisons for lower case values, too.

Comment: You need to look up a few  tutorials. You are closing your if statement before if executes, using == instead of .equals() to compare strings and using a break statement despite the fact you aren't using loops.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help, I have got it working and learnt something new too. Is it possible for my if statement to use multiple strings using ||. For example:
if (input1.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello" || "Hey" || "Hi"), is there a more efficient way rather than creating multiple, else if statments

Comment: @DrKhan: Yup. That's called the or operator. In your case, it makes more sense to compare using equalsIgnoreCase(), otherwise you would have to change the || everytime you changed the input word that was being compared.

Comment: @DrKhan you can't use `||` inside String.equalsIgnoreCase. To get the result you're going for you'd need to do `if(input1.equalsIgnoreCase("hello") || input1.equalsIgnoreCase("hey") || input1.equalsIgnoreCase("hi")){/*conditions*/}`

Comment: @DrKhan:- I have updated my answer for your query regarding OR. Check it out :)

Comment: I'll just point out that my original "Yup" is now wrong as you've changed the comment I replied to! Follow @seren01's comment instead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never use `==` to compare strings.

use `.equals` instead.

```
if (input1.equals("Hello"))
```

or

```
if (input1.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello"))
```

Delete the semicolon at the end of

```
if (input1 == "Hello");
```

**EDIT:- As seen in your comments regarding OR.**

You can try this:-

```
if(input1.equalsIgnoreCase("hello") || input1.equalsIgnoreCase("hey") || input1.equalsIgnoreCase("hi"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `;` at the end of your if statement. And use `.equals()` to compare strings.

The semicolon causes the compile error, while the `==` will cause a logical error once it does run.

Comment: @JoshM: the semicolon causes a compilation error on the `else`.

Comment: If we want to bug someone to modify the compiler to give a warning when this type of semicolon error appears, whom should we contact?  This question keeps coming up over and over.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want the semicolon on the line

```
if (input1 == "Hello");
```

You also probably do not actually want to compare using `==` (read the linked question about comparing strings).

Third, why is there a `break` statement in your `else` clause?

Comment: To expand on the third point here (for the OP), break statements are used to exit loops - you don't have a loop, so there's no need for it to be there.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29).  This compares two Strings without any regard to case.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `;` after your `if` statement condition and add a `{` after `else`. Also, it is good practice to to use the `equals(Object)` method when comparing objects because you might get unexpected results when using `==`.